# find type exceptions with name methods

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Is any way to find out types of exceptions arise with name method.
For example I use "delete" function of Hbase table to delete some columns and I want to know what exceptions can be arise?

Comment: As I understand you right, if you use Eclipse, select your function (`delete` for example), press `F2` and see documentation of current method. There should be provided Exception type on failure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you right, if you use Eclipse, select your function (delete for example), press F2 and see documentation of current method.

There should be provided Exception type on failure.

Further, you can use try/catch option (sometimes Eclipse creates proper Exception type)

Right click on method -> Surround With

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the api

http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#delete(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Delete)

delete throws IOException